# In Unix, delete a file listed in the directory but missing from the filesystem

Tags: linux, macos, unix, filesystems

I, like an idiot, killed my `rm -rf` command in the middle of it, and now there's one file remaining, but it keeps saying access is denied.  I assumed it was because a process was accessing it, but when I run `lsof` on the file, it says `No such file or directory`.

My new hypothesis is that the directory file has the file listed, but the data of the file has been removed.  I'm much more of a Windows guy, but my laptop is running OS X, which is where I did this.

Can someone tell me how to either delete this file record forcibly or further debug the situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Try a `fsck` on that filesystem.  You may have to boot  into recovery mode to do that (i.e. if it's in the rootfs and therefore not unmountable).

Comment: If you run the commands you mentioned and `ls -la` and post the results in your question ([edit] your question), that might help us (or maybe even you) to debug the situation further.